# Between point to point connectivity and remote network access, which is riskier?

Tags: network, audit, third-party

Between point to point connectivity and remote network access, which is riskier? If I have a third party accessing my company's network, which are the different modes through which they can access and what would be the order of risk for each kind of network connection?

Comment: WoT has a good answer to your second question below.  Regarding your first question, well, I won't post my "answer" as an answer because it's really not, but my non-answer: either one can be very risky, if setup, configured, and/or maintained poorly. Remote access (meaning, I assume, a user can access your network from pretty much any location/ip address they want) is classically considered very problematic to secure, for good reason. But with care (and maybe a VPN endpoint that requires TPM-secured attestation/authentication of remote PCs, plus strong passwords) it can be done. More or less.

Comment: Likewise, point-to-point using an IPsec tunnel is often regarded as a nicely secure way of doing things, and it often is.  But if set-up improperly it can certainly create a vulnerable point in your defenses. And either way, you'll still be confronted with the most difficult challenge regarding third-party access to your network: how do you either (1) make sure the connecting third-party's security is robust or (2) strictly limit the extent of the third-party's access to your network to reduce the risk that their poor security poses to you while still letting them do what they need to?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question. You must start with a blank sheet of paper and draw **what** (application, service, ,...) needs to be accessed by **whom** (local or remote users, ...) and **how** (via which route).

With this in mind you must decide what is the most restrictive access you can afford, starting with having your service hosted on Internet without connectivity to your network (which will probably not work) and then slowly bringing it in through the network layers (DMZ, LAN, ...). At the same time look at how the third party will access the service (it does not have to be VPN, it could be SSL to an application, or a virtual desktop, ...).

This is to say that there is no definite answer to your question, it is entirely dependent on the service, on your network configuration, and the general architecture.

EDIT following comment (very broadly):

- VPN: an extension of the network which bridges a computer to a computer, a computer to a network or a network to a network
- virtual desktop: a service which provides a virtual environment (equivalent to a physical desktop) which is accessed via a browser or a specific client (RDP for instance).
- Application: access to data is done via a web application, directly exposed to Internet, or limited to a set of IPs, to browsers which can provide a certificate, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So could you explain the difference between VPN and an SSL to an application, and again a virtual desktop?

Comment: @KarthikRamakrishnan: I updated my answer, you will find plenty of information available in Internet